# slow http connection in LAN

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, http

I have a weird problem I'm trying to solve, but can't find out how. I found that problem when trying to access a php page and only the basic html and css were loaded but the flash didn't. when I tried to download the swf file directly, I encountered an http timeout error.

In order to find the problem I ran some tests:
1) when I downloaded a file via FTP, the download speed was ok.
2) when I downloaded a BIG file (100M) via http - the download speed also was ok.
3) when I downloaded a small file (50K) via http - the download speed was very slow. I tried several file extensions but it gave the same result. This is the reason for the flash swf file to not load successfully - due to a timeout.
**Edit**: the file is downloaded, but corrupted since data is missing in the middle of the file

The most interesting part is that when I access the same page via localhost or outside of the network (s.a via ppp interface over cellular modem) the files are loaded perfectly. Therefore, the problem is only for LAN.

The server is apache2, over Ubuntu 10.04.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more like some sort of LAN issue, either the network itself, the client machine, or the server. This is supported by you mentioning you are getting corrupted data in the middle of the file assumably over the LAN but not localhost/PPP.

I would try and narrow down the issue. A few things you can check:

- Is it just HTTP or all other services being affected on the LAN?
- Is it just this one server or all machines on the LAN?
- Is it just outgoing data or incoming data?
- Are there any relevant log messages (Apache, boot-up, system, etc...)?
- Are there any firewalls (software/hardware) on the LAN that might be causing an issue?

Don't ignore the possibility of rare things like bad hardware (network card, router, switch, cable, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Only for LAN but not with "localhost" or over PPP? Sounds like a resolving issue to me.
Check your DNS-settings on the server: e.g. /etc/resolv.conf, local running BIND-server and look for wrong entries in /etc/hosts

Comment: i'm not connecting via DNS, but only by IP. does it still counts?

Comment: Yes, it still counts.

Comment: can you please specify what might be a wrong entry in those /etc/hosts?